# How to find the accumulation points of a recursively defined sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $a_1=0$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n+3}+2$. How do I find the accumulation points? 
Could someone show me this task as an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints. Try them out.

1. A monotone and bounded sequence is convergent.
2. If $(a_n)$ is convergent, then $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n  a_{n+1}$.